# ASP.Net Gridview border not displaying in IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I am working on an ASP.Net website and have a GridView displaying some data,in the `OnRowDataBound` event I am setting the border of the row for certain rows based on some criteria.

This all worked fine when I was testing my pages locally, however when I put these pages within our master page (this is part of a company intranet site) the row borders disappear in IE yet display fine in firefox.

Is there anything that could be causing this? So far there is no CSS style applied that I know of as I set the border inside the event handler like so:

```
 e.Row.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
 e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#fed69c")
 e.Row.BorderColor = Color.FromName("Red")
 e.Row.BorderWidth = "2"
```

Update:

This is the CSS i grabbed from the developer tools in IE:

```
height: 12px; 
border-top-color: red; 
border-right-color: red; 
border-bottom-color: red; 
border-left-color: red; 
border-top-width: 2px; 
border-right-width: 2px; 
border-bottom-width: 2px; 
border-left-width: 2px;
border-top-style: solid; 
border-right-style: solid; 
border-bottom-style: solid; 
border-left-style: solid; 
background-color: rgb(253, 254, 156);
```

My Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTickets" 
                                runat="server" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                DataKeyNames="TicketID" 
                                AllowSorting="true" 
                                DataSourceID="dsGridview" 
                                GridLines="Horizontal" 
                                OnRowDataBound="gvTickets_RowDataBound"
                                EnableViewState="True" 
                                RowStyle-Height="12px" 
                                Width="100%" 
                                BackColor="White" 
                                Font-Size="10px">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug using IE F12 tools to see what style is being applied to the border of the GridView. Possilby inherited from the master page. You can change CSS sttribute setting from the tool and viiew the results live. You might also try setting the BorderWidth property.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the code I grabbed from the IE debug and according to the style applied to the row it should be displaying correctly :S I also had the border width property set I just missed copy pasting it into my question.

Answer (score 1):

just tried it out, with master/content page and it showed correct(kinda ugly colors hehe) but it showed fine.  One suggestion I can give you is use Google Chrome, right click on the page and select "Inspect Element" it will show any css that it may be apply to your gridview rows.  Even though you didn't set a css in your page but there might be one on your masterpage.

Comment: Thanks, The problem is that it displays correctly in Firefox / chrome but not IE, after inspecting in IE though I posted the results as an edit to my original question.

Comment: can you post the format you have on the gridview? or atleast make sure there's no formatting in your aspx file.

Comment: I have posted the gridview, other than what you see above I do no formatting etc.

Comment: wow this is a weird one, I just tried the same settings for the gridview that you have and it comes out correct..Have you tried clearing your cache in IE or the compatibility view see if that's causing it to happen?

Comment: Yep, Tried clearing the cache, I also tried setting the border colour using attribute.add which works for the background of the row but never for the border colour, I cant seem to find a way around this one!